# Default button in asp.net (Master Page)?

Tags: asp.net

in my web application i have a master page and i want to implement defaultbutton for a login page when user press enter (my application has Master page) how can i place default button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with Master Pages - have a look here for how Web Browsers interprept the forms.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924062349/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx)

Personally I would enclose the form in its own Panel control and set the defaultbutton property to that of the submit button.

NOTE: This will only work in ASP.NET 2.0 and above.

Comment: Actually in the link you posted, several people commented on issues with master pages and the default button

Answer (score 17):

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = crtlLoginUserLogin.FindControl("LoginButton").UniqueID
```

or just

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = LoginButton.UniqueID
```

This will work.

Comment: I am using master page Mr. Five Tools how can it is possible

Comment: you can use the above code in the page load event of your login page - regardless of the master page that's related to it.  The ctrlLoginUserLogin I mention above is an asp:login i have on a page in one of my apps.  Works fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a default button in a Master Page, and the button is in a Content Page or a User Control, you cannot set this directly in the Master Page markup.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="MyButton" >
```

Will generate the following error:

*The DefaultButton of 'form1' must be the ID of a control of type IButtonControl.*

The workaround for this is to set the default button during the Page_Load of your Content/User Control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button myButton = (Button)FindControl("MyButton");

            Page.Form.DefaultButton = myButton.UniqueID;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The VB version of this is as follows:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load      
       'cast the master page form to set the default values for the Default button and Default focus'
       Dim myForm As HtmlForm = TryCast(Me.Master.FindControl("myMasterForm"), HtmlForm)
       myForm.DefaultButton = Me.btnAdd.UniqueID
       myForm.DefaultFocus = Me.txtMyTextbox.UniqueID
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, There is a BuiltIn Control designed for Login called as [LoginView](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/tutorial-02-cs.aspx).
It integrates into your Master page or any other page and could provide full use of the authentication system. Here is the code for it

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
</asp:LoginView>
```

Asp.Net provides a complete framework for authentication and authorization of an application. I would recommend having a look at if you are about to implement one for your application and you have not reviewed it as option already.

- [**Security Framework For Asp.Net**](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/)

**EDIT:** If you want a button to be place over master page, Drag and Drop the button like we do for a normal Web-form and Implement following event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Response.Redirect("MyApplication/SomePage.aspx");
    }
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: Just Drag and Drop a button control Like we do for Web-Forms!! and implment the event Click for it. Check Edit

Answer (score 0):

```
(Page.Master.FindControl("Form1") as HtmlForm).DefaultButton = this.cmdSubmit.UniqueID;
```

From [http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/06/21/asp-net-default-button-and-master-pages/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120628172543/http://www.dotnetthoughts.net:80/2010/06/21/asp-net-default-button-and-master-pages/)