# Set Default Button Enter - Master Page

Tags: asp.net

Hi everybody i have the next problem. I have to set a button as default when i press Enter. I can use DefaultButton in the Form because now all my pages inherits from Master Page and i have a Content from the Master Page and this isn't work. Somebody could give me any alternative to solve this please. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212928/default-button-in-asp-net-master-page

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but this work when the page isn't inherits from Master Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Enter Key - Default Submit Button](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/04/12/74951.aspx):

> ASP.NET 2.0 introduces a wonderful work around for this. By simply
>   specifying the "defaultbutton" property to the ID of the ,
>   whose event you want to fire, your job is done.
>
> The defaultbutton property can be specified at the Form level in the
>   form tag as well as at panel level in the  definition tag.
>   The form level setting is overridden when specified at the panel
>   level, for those controls that are inside the panel.
>
> Also, the Event Handler for the specified button, fires thereby
>   simulating a true submit button functionality.

Like this

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1">
<div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Or you can achieve this by

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = crtlLoginUserLogin.FindControl("LoginButton").UniqueID
```

or just

```
Page.Form.DefaultButton = LoginButton.UniqueID
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is through to recursively search through all your child pages controls and find the first button, get the id and set the default button of your form.

Although I have never tried this, I dont think its a very good idea as it is slow and error prone.

An alternative may be to do it through javascript/jquery, see this answer:
[Submit form with Enter key without submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981637/submit-form-with-enter-key)